# How do you route root requests to a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a controller called Videos. I'd like my URLs to be like this:

```
http://website/1
```

Rather than this:

```
http://website/videos/1
```

I'd also like to keep the functionality of controlling its content via `/videos/` (edit, new, destroy, etc). Basically the `show` action is the only one that would be responding from root.

Is there a way to do this without messing up with the other controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `/:id` route, that links to `videos#show`:

```
get '/:id' => 'videos#show'
```

You'll need to put this near the bottom of your routes file so that it doesn't match requests for things like `/videos`.

Comment: @DeepakMahakale I specifically said this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create all RESTful routes for a controller, without its name in path by using

> resources :videos, path: ""

This will create all routes for videos controller like (index, new, edit, create etc)

If you want only a specific route to serve as this then you can pass that  too with this like

> resources :videos, path: "", only:[:show]

This will create only your desired path

http://website/1

and will not affect any other controllers.